# Swift - sort the results from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase-storage

How can I sort the results obtained from Storage?
I am downloading a list of files from Storage and
I would like to sort the results by file name.

This is my code

```
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(categoryName)

    storageRef.listAll { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {

       print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

        else{

            for item in result.items {


                let videoStorageRef = storageRef.child(item.name).downloadURL { (url, error) in

                    if let error = error {

                       print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }

                        else{

                        // do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you want to sort result.items by a property `name?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
result.items.sorted(by: { $0.name > $1.name })
```